# Why is DateTime altering timezone in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

```
$datetime = new DateTime( gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'), new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
$past_time = $datetime->createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $past_time )->getTimestamp();
echo 'Past formed: ' . gmdate('H:i:s', $past_time ) . '<br><br>';
```

Is outputting:

```
2016-09-09 14:42:50
Past formed: 12:42:50


$past_time = $row->date_added;
```

Where date added is in a MySQL database and is equal to:

```
2016-09-09 14:42:50
```

I'm not changing the timezone, I'm merely converting a timestamp back into gmdate()

At which point is the time having 2 hours taken off it and how do I prevent it?

**Edit**

```
$datetime = new DateTime( gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'), new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
$past_time = $datetime->createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $past_time, new DateTimeZone('UTC') )->getTimestamp();
echo 'Past formed: ' . gmdate('H:i:s', $past_time ) . '<br><br>';
```

This was the solution, I had to set the timezone despite never changing it

It must make sense in a round-a-bout way, but I still don't really understand where DateTime is getting its "from and to"

Comment: Maybe from the  `'U'`, why are you using it !?-- forget this comment

Comment: I've tried getTimestamp() but the result is the same

Comment: Thing thats the problem: `gmdate():Identical to the date() function except that the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).`  use `date()` instead of `gmdate()`

Comment: When you do this `$datetime = new DateTime( gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s') );` it's going to create a datetime in the local time zone.

Comment: Another note: $past_time is NOT defined here `$datetime->createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $past_time )`. :)

Comment: I've changed the timezone to UTC, but the error is still there

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of using `createFromFormat` *on an existing instance*…?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I've updated the code and attempted to force the timezone to UTC

Comment: Come on, dont use `gmdate()` if not needed and use `DateTime` simple as possible, like @deceze noted. What are you try to do?

Comment: if you have string like `2016-02-12 12:00:12` use `strtotime()`to get a timestamp, then use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$timestamp)` to format it. thats all..

Comment: @deceze I added the timezone to createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $past_time, new DateTimeZone('UTC') )->getTimestamp(); and it worked

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. What's the point of the whole `$datetime` instance? Doesn't look like it serves any purpose. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? You're clearly overcomplicating *something*, and that makes it unclear what the purpose of this code is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2016-09-09 14:42:50` is an **incomplete** timestamp, it is missing the timezone information. Without timezone information, this timestamp could refer to any of over 24 different **absolute** points in time. `14:42:50` in London, England occurs several hours after `14:42:50` in Tokyo, Japan.

`DateTime` instances and UNIX timestamps (created with `time()` or `strtotime()`) are **absolute** points in time, they don't have and aren't influenced by timezones. When converting `2016-09-09 14:42:50` into one of these absolute timestamps, PHP needs to infer the missing information (the timezone) from somewhere. If you do not supply the information explicitly, it takes it from [`date_default_timezone_get`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_get).

```
$datetime = new DateTime( gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'), new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
$past_time = $datetime->createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $past_time )->getTimestamp();
```

Let's get rid of the completely superfluous `$datetime` instance here for simplicity…

```
$past_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $past_time)->getTimestamp();
```

`createFromFormat` here is reading the incomplete timestamp and infers its timezone. That is where the mismatch is happening, it assumes a timezone other than what the timestamp actually represents. Hence the result is offset by a few hours. `getTimestamp` than merely reformats that into a different, but still absolute, format of a UNIX timestamp.

```
echo 'Past formed: ' . gmdate('H:i:s', $past_time) . '<br><br>';
```

`gmdate` reads the UNIX timestamp and outputs it converted to the GMT timezone. `date` uses the `date_default_timezone_get` timezone, `gmdate` always uses GMT.

You've got a whole lot of unnecessary conversions going on here. The only thing you really need is:

```
$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $past_time, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo 'Past formed: ', $timestamp->format('H:i:s');
```

1. Ensure you complete the correct timezone information when converting from `2016-09-09 14:42:50` to a `DateTime` instance.
2. Format the `DateTime` instance in the desired format.

Comment: Thank you, I learned something and your post is very detailed, I appreciate your time taken

Answer (score 0):

Thing the issue is, when calling this line:

`echo 'Past formed: ' . gmdate('H:i:s', $past_time ) . '<br><br>';`

gmdate() looks up the current DateTimeZone in your PHP script, and acts on that.

So you have to use this first for the global timezone:

`date_default_timezone_set()`

Test what you have set up `print date_default_timezone_get();`